# I try to use useState but dont works weirdly

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I used the useState of react to deal with "hooks" (is the name of it?)

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState(null);
```

In the next piece of code I use the `setUsers` but dosnt do it...

```
        getUsersApi(queryString.stringify(params)).then(response => {
            console.log(params.page)
            // eslint-disable-next-line eqeqeq
            if(params.page == "1"){
                console.log(response)//line33
                if(isEmpty(response)){
                    setUsers([]);
                }else{
                    setUsers(response);
                    console.log(users);//line38
                }
            }else{
                if(!response){
                    setBtnLoading(0);
                }else{
                    setUsers({...users, ...response});
                    setBtnLoading(false);
                }
            }
            
        })
```

I inserted a `console.log` inside of it and apparently pass through there, but dosnt set users...
[image]

Here is the function `getUsersApi()` in case you need it.

```
export function getUsersApi(paramsUrl){
    console.log(paramsUrl)
    const url = `${API_HOST}/users?${paramsUrl}`
    const params = {
        headers:{
        Authorization: `Bearer${getTokenApi()}`,
        },
    };
    return fetch(url, params).then(response => {
        return response.json();
    }).then(result => {
        return result;
    }).catch(err => {
        return err;
    });
}
```

Here is the function `isEmpty()` in case you need it.

```
    function isEmpty(value) {
      if (value == null) {
        return true;
      }
      if (isArrayLike(value) &&
          (isArray(value) || typeof value == 'string' || typeof value.splice == 'function' ||
            isBuffer(value) || isTypedArray(value) || isArguments(value))) {
        return !value.length;
      }
      var tag = getTag(value);
      if (tag == mapTag || tag == setTag) {
        return !value.size;
      }
      if (isPrototype(value)) {
        return !baseKeys(value).length;
      }
      for (var key in value) {
        if (hasOwnProperty.call(value, key)) {
          return false;
        }
      }
      return true;
    }
```

Thanks a lot guys!!

Comment: Can you provide your `isEmpty` function

Comment: ```import {isEmpty} from "lodash";```

Comment: Ignore my concern above. Your `users` should already be set in the next render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know if the state has been updated, be sure to set a useEffect hook with the state inside the dependency array.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

useEffect(() => {
   console.log("Users: ", users)
}, [users])
```

If this gets logged, users have been sucessfully updated.

If this does **NOT** gets logged, you're not entering the `else` which calls `setUsers`

Comment: I will use this tip! Thanks

Comment: yes! i tried it and wasnt the error where i thought could be. Thanks!